# ntfs cluster allocation

Tags: ntfs

I'm interested in finding out how cluster allocation by NTFS works agaings write/IRP. NTFS does store this information in MFT but what actually happens at that time. Is there an I/O object in the kernel that stores this information before the data is flush to the disk or does USN journal plays any role here. If so how.

Answer (score 1):

NTFS has to look up where the data actually is on the volume, that's its job. The O/S provides something called a, "Map Control Block" (MCB) package that the file systems use to cache this information, but if it's not in the MCB it has to be looked up from the MFT. The USN is different, that's just logging various events.

If you're interested in Windows file systems I suggest reading the file systems internals book:

[http://www.amazon.com/Windows-System-Internals-Classic-Reprints/dp/0976717514/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1309880147&sr=8-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0976717514)

As well as taking a look at the FAT source in the WDK, which is a great starting point compared to NTFS (NTFS is much more complicated).

-scott